# Swift 4 GIDSignIn "undeclared type" error

Tags: ios, google-api, swift4

I am trying to integrate a google sign in to my app and for some reason, in my AppDelegate.swift when I try to implement "GIDSignInDelegate", and anything GIDSignIn related, it flags it as "undeclared type" or "use of unresolved identifier". If anyone has any suggestions please let me know! Thanks in advance :)[AppDelegate.swift screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpVXx.png)

Comment: Don't add screenshot of code instead copy pate in question , If you have added pod then you have to open **xcworkspace** project or try to restart xcode with clean derived  data

Answer (score 0):

There are different pod names in different documents. If you are using `Google/SignIn (3.1.0)` pod, this code will work for you:

```
import Google

class AppDelegate:UIResponder,GIDSignInDelegate{
....
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "your_client_id"
  GIDSignIn.delegate = self
  .....
  ....
}
```